# create online files

Tags: php

i want to make some .doc files with some entries in a database.
here is what i wrote:

```
$name1=$user->username;
$name2=$nume;
$name3=$_POST['util'];
$cale="../doc/"; 
$file_name=$name1 . "_" .$name2."_".$name3;

$fp = fopen($cale, $file_name . ".doc", 'w+'); 

$message="Zhtml>Zbody> <table width='100%' border='0'>
<tr>
<td align='center' width='15%'>Data citire </td>
<td align='center' width='15%'>Index </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align='center' width='15%'>CURRENT_DATE()</td>
<td align='center' width='15%'>".$_POST['ind']."</td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
";
fwrite($fp, $message);
fclose($fp);`
```

On localhost it works great, but when i upload it to a server it doesn't create the files..
I've set the permissions to 777 but still no luck.
also i've tried with other paths, even with no path. still nothing.
can someone help?

thank's
Sebastian

EDIT:
clearly the path is the problem, i made the whole site 777 and the file is created in the root folder.
i tried this:
`$cale=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/components/com_calculator/doc/';`

but nothing. any ideas?

Comment: First, add some formatting to your code, it will help us help you :D. (Indent by four spaces for block, surround with backticks (`) for inline) Second, is it a server you control, or like a shared host? Third, what software is it using? Apache, IIS, etc?

Comment: Your code seems to be correct,just double check path ($cale) and chmod.

Comment: It's Apache.
i need this in stead of pdf export (i had some problems with pdf "the file does not start with -%PDF-" or something like that).
i guess i found the problem.

the path is wrong.
it worked with "../doc"
but instead of the doc folder it saved the file to the root folder of the site.

what is the right way to specify the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fp = fopen($cale . $file_name . ".doc", 'w+');
```

That needs changing to what I have put here. You used a comma instead of a period, meaning it was taking it to mean the method was `$file_name . ".doc"`